# PHP Ajax Form, What If The JS Was Disabled

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a simple PHP form like

```
<form action="" id="searchForm">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="theName" placeholder="Your Name" />
            <button id="send">Send data</button>
 </form>
```

and I am using ajax to send the POST values to the PHP file

```
    $("#send").on("click", function(){
     var name= $('#theName').val();
     var data='name='+name; 
     var request = $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "assets/map.php",
                           data: data,
                           cache: false
      });

    });
```

This works correctly when using JavaScript but I am thinking what if the JS was disabled in a browser? How we can still send the data to the server? should I add the `map.php` file into the form `action` attribute? if so how to prevent sending double `POST[]` values?

Comment: You should add the map.php in your action form to make it work for browser without JS, don't forget to change your map.php to do a redirect if the request type if GET

Comment: than there is no use of ajax ask user to enable js or just move on

Comment: Put the URL in your `form`s action and just prevent the default action in your JS function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use onsubmit and prevent the default action (the ordinary submit action) for the JS part, then indeed fill in the action attribute with the same url that you use for the ajax post.

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var name= $('#theName').val();
     var data='name='+name; 
     var request = $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "assets/map.php",
                       data: data,
                       cache: false
      });

    });
```

And the HTML:

```
<form action="assets/map.php" id="searchForm" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="theName" placeholder="Your Name" />
        <button id="send" type="submit">Send data</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should probably also mention to put `method="post"` on the form. Otherwise the data will be send as `$_GET` variables when JS is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

First add `assets/map.php` to your action.

Then change your jquery to this:

```
$("#send").on("click", function(){
    var name= $('#theName').val();
    var data='name='+name; 
    var request = $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "assets/map.php",
                         data: data,
                         cache: false
    });
    return false; //prevents action
});
```

As you can see this will only prevent the action if the jquery has ran.

Comment: _assets/map.php_ (as in the `url: "assets/map.php"`)